# Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I tried to change it to $y" + y = (14\sin x-28 \sin^3 x)$. The complementary solution is $C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x$ and the particular solution to $y" + y = 14 \sin x$ is $-7\sin x$. How do you find the particular solution to $y" + y = -28\sin^3 x$ ?
What would be your guess?

Ans: $$c_1 \sin(x\sqrt2)+c_2\cos(s\sqrt2)-7\sin x-\sin(3x)$$

Comment: You have the right idea, you need to convert $\sin(x)\cos(2x)$ into terms of sines and cosines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double-angle formula, you can rewrite $\sin(x)\cos(2x)$ as
$$ \sin(x)\cos(2x) = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(3x) - \sin(x)].$$ 
Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\sin(3x) = \sin(2x + x) & = \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x) \\
\sin(x) = \sin(2x-x) & = \sin(2x)\cos(x) - \cos(2x)\sin(x).
\end{align*}
Thus, this gives
$$ y'' + y = 7[\sin(3x) - \sin(x)].$$
Since there is no first derivative involved, normally one would guess a particular solution of the form
$$y_p(x) = A\sin(3x) + B\sin(x).$$
Since $\sin(x)$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation $y''+y=0$, one should now guess a particular solution of the form
$$ y_p(x) = A\sin(3x) + Bx\sin(x) + Cx\cos(x). $$

Comment: cos 2x  =  cos2 x – sin2 x     or              cos 2x  =  2 cos2 x – 1      or                cos 2x  =  1 – 2 sin2 x  are the only trig identities

Comment: You mean you are only allowed to use those identities? Otherwise, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: where did the 14 go?

Comment: Opps forgot about the 14, just added that.

Comment: The answers shown but if I do it your way I get -9Asin3x-Bsinx+Asin3x+Bsinx=14sin3x-14sinx and I get -7/2 sin3x

Comment: See my latest edit, sorry I forgot about the complementary solution. I don't see how one would get terms involving $\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$ and $\cos(\sqrt{2}x)$ thou.

Comment: Found another mistake, apologise for that. I hope it's correct now...